# how to test a gem's file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a gem inside my Rails project, really simple, it translate an ip address to a real address (e.g. `Gem.locate '127.0.0.1'` returns `{ country: 'de' }`

The code is like this

**ip_locator/lib/service.rb**

```
module IpLocator
  class Service
    include Singleton

    attr_reader :db
    def initialize
      @db = MaxMindDB.new('db/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
    end

    def locate(ip)
      db.lookup ip
    end
  end
end
```

when I'm in the rails project, I can properly do this: `IpLocator::Service.instance.locate '74.125.225.224'` and get the information I need.
Now I'm trying add some tests to the gem (not in the rails project).

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe IpLocator do
  describe 'ip_locator' do
    context 'when the data exists' do
      let(:ip) { '74.125.225.224' }
      subject do
        IpLocator::Service.instance.locate ip
      end
      it 'return country data' do
        expect(subject.found).to be_truthy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but when I run the test, I get

```
  1) IpLocator ip_locator when the data exists return country data
     Failure/Error: IpLocator::Service.instance.locate ip

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant IpLocator::Service
```

I already tried to change `IpLocator::Service` to `Service`, I tried require `ip_locator` inside the spec file (although it is already required inside `spec_helper.rb`). I'm pretty sure I'm doing something really stupid but not sure what exactly

Here is my `spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.setup
require 'byebug'
require 'ip_locator'
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Enable flags like --only-failures and --next-failure
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = '.rspec_status'

  # Disable RSpec exposing methods globally on `Module` and `main`
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
end
```

and I'm seeing the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant IpLocator::Service::Singleton
Did you mean?  SignalException
```

then, if I try to require `singleton` as well in the spec_helper, I get

```
  1) IpLocator::Service ip_locator when the data exists return country data
     Failure/Error: @db = ::MaxMindDB.new('db/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant MaxMindDB
```

I'm getting crazy

Comment: I think you need to be describing the object rather than the engine, describe Service do

Comment: I tried `describe Service` and `IpLocator::Service`, none of them worked

Comment: You should `require` your lib code in your test.  Rails auto-requires everything but a lot of other Ruby code does not.

Comment: did that...edited the answer to include what else I did

Comment: aaand edited again. this makes no sense

Comment: Have looked in a spec_helper I have in an engine and found:

Comment: ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../spec/dummy/config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'coveralls'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'timecop'
Dir[File.expand_path("../../spec/factories/**/*.rb",__FILE__)].each{|f| load f}
Dir[File.expand_path("../../spec/support/**/*.rb",__FILE__)].each {|f| require f}
include Devise::TestHelpers # see spec/support/devise.rb
include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers

Comment: Apart from that my spec file in the engine is pretty much identical and loads classes as it should

Comment: Also just to confirm these tests are being added to the engine's spec folder and not the main app's ?

Comment: actually, it is not an engine, it is pure ruby gem...and I figured out how to "kinda" fix: `Gem.loaded_specs['ip_locator'].dependencies.each do |gem| require gem.name; end`. it runs as expected when I'm inside the `gems/ip_locator` folder, but not when I'm in the app root folder